# Why is clearRect not working properly in this case?

Tags: javascript, canvas

This is what I have, but `clearRect` is not working as I expect. The box let a trail.

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script>

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");

var x=0;
!function loop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.rect(x++, 10, 80, 80);
    ctx.stroke();
}();

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to `ctx.clearRect`.

`ctx.rect` adds to a [*path*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Drawing_paths), but you are never starting or ending a new path, so all the calls to `ctx.rect` will add to the very same path, accumulating rectangular shapes.

Either start and end a new path:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(x++, 10, 80, 80);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

or use [`ctx.strokeRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#strokeRect%28%29):

```
ctx.strokeRect(x++, 10, 80, 80);
```